# Proxy Pattern and the Holder Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

A couple questions in my text book are kind of tricky to me:

1. "The Proxy Pattern is best described by which of the following statements"

   A. Allows access to a component through accessor/mutator methods

   B. Allows an object to reference and send messages to another object that changes frequently
2. "The Holder Pattern is best described by which of the following statements?"

   A. Allows access to a component through accessor/mutator methods

   B. Allows an object to reference and send messages to another object that changes frequently

I think that the answer to question 1 is B and  the answer to question 2 is A. I think these answers because the proxy pattern provides access to an **object** (not a component) to more than one other object through using accessor and mutator methods. However I am unsure and wanted to know the correct answers.

Comment: i don't know holder pattern :( and when i google it jumps Proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your teacher probably wants to hear is 1A 2B.

Both patterns do very similar things, but the holder pattern is used for providing constant access to frequently changing object references.

In short, the proxy pattern just accesses a different object, while the holder pattern exists to access whatever object it holds at the time.

Comment: However using mutator/accessor (aka setter/getter) is never the aim for proxy.  Just curious, for so-called Holder, does it refers to things like StringHolder in Java?  If so, neither answer seems correct for its aim too.

Comment: @AdrianShum this text book usually uses a ColorHolder when it talks about the holder pattern, so I think the answer is relative.

Comment: @Jan Therefore, it is correct to say proxy pattern and holder pattern achieve same thing (access to getters/setters/member functions) and in proxy pattern, 'proxied object' doesnt change, but in holder pattern here must be provision for runtime modification of 'proxied object' ?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to search a bit on what is so-called Holder pattern (and I found cs.brown.edu/courses/cs015/lectures/DesignPattern.pptx which contains "ColorHolder" that OP mentioned in a comment, I bet they are referring to same thing)  . Here is my view on the question:

Question 1:

Neither of the answers describe the aim for Proxy.  Main aim of a proxy is to provide a level of indirection for access to another object.  There are various reason for such indirection: we want to provide certain subset of feature of the proxied object, or we want to make a remote object looks like a local one, etc.  Answer A is not reasonable because accessor/mutator (getter/setter) is never the aim for Proxy.  Answer B is not reasonable either because whether the proxied object is changing frequently or not is never the main reason for proxy.

However answer B seems a bit closer to the purpose of Proxy, as it mentioned about "another object" which is a very important element of Proxy.

Question 2:

So called Holder pattern is not a general pattern.  It is simply a pattern to deal with immutable object + pass-by-value constraints.

Assume I want to call method `void foo(Bar bar)` and I want foo to change the bar parameter, and I want such change to be visible to caller.   Because Java (and some similar languages) only allow pass-by-value, we cannot change the bar reference to point to another object.  If bar is made to be immutable, we also lose the possibility to change the state of bar directly.  In such case we make a so-called Holder, which provide you getter and setter to let the `foo` method able "change" the reference of bar which is visible to caller.

Another use is we want several obj to refer to same value.  If each obj refers to that value individually, if I change the value thru object 1, it is not visible to other "referred" object.  Therefore Holder acts as an extra level of indirection: all obj refers to the Holder and such reference is never changed.  We change the value by changing the value held by Holder.

(In C/C++ it can be done by simply pointer to pointer)

Neither answer best describe such use but A is a bit closer because getter/setter (aka accessor/mutator) is what a Holder normally provides.

Comment: So my answer is totally opposite to the other answer in the question :P  However, I just feel the question is poorly asked, as none of the answer actually describes the aim for the patterns